# Constant $c$ for a given cdf function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Assume that there is a random variable $X$ with cdf function
\begin{align}
F(x) = c\left(\dfrac{10}{9} - xe^{-x} \right)
\end{align}
for $x \in [3.1, +\infty)$. I'd like to obtain constant $c$. So I have two ideas.

**Approach 1**

We know that for any cdf the condition
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} F(x) = 1
\end{align}
must be fulfilled, so that gives
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} c\left(\dfrac{10}{9} - xe^{-x} \right) = c\dfrac{10}{9} = 1
\end{align}
because
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{x \to +\infty} xe^{-x} = 0
\end{align}
as $e^{x}$ goes to infinity much faster than $x$ (or with d'Hospital rule). Therefore
\begin{align}
c = \dfrac{9}{10}
\end{align}
**Approach 2**
Let's compute pdf
\begin{align}
f(x) = F'(x) = c\left(\dfrac{10}{9} - xe^{-x} \right)' = c(xe^{-x} -e^{-x})
\end{align}
Now
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{3.1}^{+\infty} f(x) = 1
\end{align}
so
\begin{align}
\int\limits_{3.1}^{+\infty} (xe^{-x} -e^{-x}) = \lim\limits_{T \to +\infty} -xe^{-x} + 3.1e^{-3.1} = 3.1e^{-3.1} = \dfrac{1}{c}
\end{align}
thus
\begin{align}
c = \dfrac{e^{3.1}}{3.1}
\end{align}
These two results are totally different. Where's the mistake?

**EDIT** this $F(x)$ is strictly decreasing, so it makes everything even more puzzling...

Comment: $F$ is increasing. It wouldn't even have been a cdf if it was decreasing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first method is correct. The second one is not because $X$ does not even have a pdf! $P(X=3.1)>0$ so there is a  point mass at $3.1$